# nodejs which package to install "=>" lambda for parse-server

Tags: node.js, lambda, parse-server

i need to install parse-server and when i execute main.js this exceptions always occured

```
request(options, (error, response, body) => {
                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hilman/e.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

and also this one

```
return results.map(r => r.relatedId);
                         ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
        at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

which npm packages should i install to make parse-server work in my server?

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: parse server? or npm? npm i am using sudo apt-get install npm , and when i execute npm -v 1.3.10

Comment: what version of node? type "node -v" in command prompt

Comment: That version is not compatible with arrow functions, you will need to upgrade you version of node to run this module.